# Python: Threading script interfering with separate script

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a script called startup_launching.py, which does something like this:

```
import os
# launch chrome
os.startfile(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe')
```

To run this from the (windows) command line, I enter:

python "FILEPATH\startup_launching.py"

That works fine.

However, I have a separate script called threading.py, which does this:

```
import time, threading

def foo():
    print(time.ctime())
    threading.Timer(10, foo).start()

foo()
```

(which I found on stackoverflow).

When threading.py is saved in the same folder as startup_launching.py, it seems to interfere with startup_launching.py when I run it from the command line (e.g. one of the error messages is: module 'threading' has no attribute 'Timer').

When I move threading.py to another folder, startup_launching.py works fine again.

Can someone explain what's going on here? I assumed that entering:

python "FILEPATH\startup_launching.py"

in the command line would only look in startup_launching.py 
Thanks!

Comment: Don't name your python files the same as a module you're trying to import, ie: `threading.py` and `import threading`

Answer (score 0):

you should rename your file so that it is not named `threading.py`, since it will be in the import path and will mask the actual built-in `threading` module, which the other script relies upon.

Answer (score 0):

Name your module something other than threading.py because there is a built-in module named threading.py.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call it threading.py. Also, check your python version, if it correspond to the tutorial that you were reading.